# Amplitude drop as frequency increases on function generator

Tags: function-generator

As I increase the frequency on my function generator, the amplitude of the transmitted wave decreases. Is this to be expected? Or is there an issue with my function generator?

Comment: What does the user manual say about this?

Answer (score 3):

If it is an older analog function generator without a calibrated amplitude this may be normal.  More modern wave generators should have flat amplitude output. The output impedance is usually 50 ohm. If you have a frequency dependent load like a short cable and an oscilloscope with a high impedance input then this is also normal.  The function generator is doing it's thing properly but your load is a capacitor.  Try setting your scope to 50 ohm mode or using an external terminator.

Answer (score 2):

There's a concept of [slew rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slew_rate), which is how fast a signal can change it's level say volts /sec.  This is fixed for individual components and assemblies of components.  Many things govern slew rate like capacitance, current carrying capacity, what you're driving and quantum semiconductor effects.  So if you can only change level at a fixed rate, a faster frequency can only be maintained at reduced amplitude. It's a bit like this:-

[image: slew rate]

where you can see that the blue line's gradient is lower than the original wave. It's closely related to bandwidth product governing the gain of an amplifier such as those in a signal generator.  A TL081 op amp has a slew rate of 13 V/us, which creates a frequency /output curve like:-

[image: graph]